# what is the difference between I have been used and I have used?

Tags: grammaticality

What is the difference between the following sentences? When can I use either? are they both correct?

I have been used this method

and

I have used this method

Comment: The first sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is grammatically incorrect. It may be you  missed out a preposition  in between "used" and " this method ", may be a "to". In any case, the two sentences are different in meaning. While the latter suggests you have employed certain method, the former goes to mean you are accustomed to the method provided you are agreeable to use one " To " as suggested.

Comment: I just want to say that " I have used such a method to design this system"

Comment: So settle down with the second, discard the first.